# How do I deal with pip in different python versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I had python 3.8 installed and then I installed python 2.7. I am trying to run a python program with `py -2 program.py` in vs code using with python 2.7 as selected environment and I am getting an error, `ImportError: No module named googlemaps` even though I have already installed.

If I run the program using Python3 then it would run fine. Also when I open vs code using python 2.7 as selected runtime environment then I would get a warning `Linter Pylint is not installed`. If I click on install then I would get another warning `There's no Pip installer available in the selected environment`.

Also even though I have changed the python path from 3.7 to 2.7, default python version will still show up as 3.7 when I run`Python` in command line.

Things that I have tried to install the `googlemaps` module for python 2 after googling for solutions,

`pip2 install googlemaps--upgrade`

`py -2 -m pip install googlemaps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your `python2` binary located, you can just call it directly:

```py
/usr/bin/python2 -m pip install googlemaps
```

And if you're not sure where your python binary is, you can use

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

to locate it.

And if you don't have pip, you should install it by downloading this file:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

then running:

```
/usr/bin/python2 get-pip.py
```

Comment: I already have pip. Pip works perfectly when I use python 3

Comment: python2 will need its own pip

Comment: Just installed pip using the link that you have mentioned and now it's working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to install Python 3.8 using Pyenv and also when you are using different versions of python, it is very useful

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
pyenv install 3.8.1
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.1 venv
pyenv local venv
```

with pyenv local you set your version for use.
If after this you run

```
pyenv version
```

It will output to 3.8.1

With regards to pip installation, run

```
whereis python
```

and if it outputs to

> usr/bin/python2
> then you can use pip for installing python2 packages and pip3 for packages compatible to python3.